# Installing tseries on R-studio

Tags: r

I am trying to use the package `tseries` on **R-studio**.

Running the import line of code I get an error:

```
> library(tseries)
Error in library(tseries) : there is no package called ‘tseries’
```

I tried installing the relative package so, and I get the following output.

```
> install.packages("tseries", dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘/home/roberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘TTR’, ‘curl’, ‘quantmod’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/TTR_0.23-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 309148 bytes (301 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 301 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/curl_4.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 673779 bytes (657 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 657 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/quantmod_0.4.17.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 152204 bytes (148 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 148 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tseries_0.10-47.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 164796 bytes (160 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 160 KB

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/roberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘TTR’
* removing ‘/home/roberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/TTR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘TTR’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘TTR’, ‘curl’ are not available for package ‘quantmod’
* removing ‘/home/roberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/quantmod’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘quantmod’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘quantmod’ is not available for package ‘tseries’
* removing ‘/home/roberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/tseries’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tseries’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpUNGZv6/downloaded_packages’
```

The installation wasn't successful, as trying to import the library again, I get the same error as before.

```
> library(tseries)
Error in library(tseries) : there is no package called ‘tseries’
```

I also tried installing manually `curl` but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is mentioned here:

```
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
```

Do you have `libcurl` on your computer? If not, you'll need to install it with e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

in your terminal (i.e. not R) if you are on Debian or install other library if you have another OS, like mentioned above.